# How to create xyz 3d chart to plot accelerometer data using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, plot, graph, charts, 3d

I am sending data from my android device to PC as JSON. Currently, I use [Smoothie Charts](http://smoothiecharts.org/) to plot my graph. I use 3 separate colors for x, y and z coordinates of accelerometer. [Here](http://smoothiecharts.org/examples/server-load.html) you can see an example of what I have achieved currently, only difference is that, in the example, you can see 4 values plotted (in 4 different colors), and in my case, there is only 3.

My question is, is there any way I can make a 3d graph? I mean, is there any solution? Since I have x, y and z coordinates, I believe that I can make a 3d graph of my data set? My data set is nothing, but it contains just 3 values. For example, like this:

```
{{1,0,-1},{1,0,0},{1,1,1},{1,0,1},{-1,-1,0},{1,1,1},{1,0,1}}...
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: so you can draw 2d plots.now you want to draw 3d one?

Comment: yes. x, y, and z values of json as x, y, and z coordinates of 3d chart

Comment: you can do that there are lot of 3d plot libraries available.for example https://plot.ly/javascript/3d-surface-plots/

Comment: hi, is there any simple solution other than plotly?

Comment: what kind of a 3d graph you want to draw ?like tubes?or

Comment: i think surface will b the best. Whats ur opinion? do u have a any suggestions? After all, I want to plot live accelerometer values